# OSError: -2 (when using urequests module in mycropython)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm pretty new to this and am trying to use my raspberry pi pico to connect to my wifi network and then get the date and time from a website and display it on a 16x2 display. basically, it worked perfectly the first couple of time I ran the script and then suddenly refused to work giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 38, in <module>
  File "urequests.py", line 180, in get
  File "urequests.py", line 76, in request
OSError: -2
```

the code I used to do this:

```
import time
import network
import urequests
from machine import I2C, Pin
from I2C_LCD import I2CLcd

ssidRouter     = 'xxxx' #my router name
passwordRouter = 'xxxx' #my router password

i2c = I2C(1, sda=Pin(14), scl=Pin(15), freq=400000)
devices = i2c.scan()
led = Pin("LED", Pin.OUT)
poop = I2CLcd(i2c, devices[0], 2, 16)

def STA_Setup(ssidRouter,passwordRouter):
    sta_if = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    if not sta_if.isconnected():
        poop.putstr("Connecting")
        sta_if.active(True)
        sta_if.connect(ssidRouter,passwordRouter)
        while not sta_if.isconnected():
            led.value(1)
            time.sleep(0.5)
            led.value(0)
            time.sleep(0.5)
        poop.clear()


STA_Setup(ssidRouter,passwordRouter)
while True:    
    r = urequests.get("http://date.jsontest.com")
    ti = r.json()["time"]
    da = r.json()["date"]
    poop.move_to(0, 0)
    poop.putstr("Time:" + ti)
    poop.move_to(0, 1)
    poop.putstr(("Date: " + da))
    time.sleep(1)
    r.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

That error appears to be coming from [this line](https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/blob/a08087249fda8a7994f7c54ccaad29fb9fcc448a/python-ecosys/urequests/urequests.py#L76) in the `urequests` module:

```
    ai = usocket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, usocket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

If `getaddrinfo` is failing, that suggests that either your device has lost its network connection, or that there is a more general problem with DNS lookups in your environment.

Some diagnostics you can perform:

- Is the device connected to Wifi?

  ```
  >>> import network
  >>> sta_if = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
  >>> sta_if.isconnected()
  True
  ```
- Does it have a sane network configuration?

  ```
  >>> sta_if.ifconfig()
  ('192.168.1.45', '255.255.255.0', '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.1')
  ```
- Can you perform hostname lookups?

  ```
  >>> import socket
  >>> socket.getaddrinfo('www.google.com', 80, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  [(2, 1, 0, '', ('142.250.80.68', 80))]
  ```

  (You may need `import usocket` instead of `import socket`; I'm working with an esp8266 instead of a Pico.)

Comment: Thank you for the help :) so I tried it this morning again and now it worked first time. No idea why. but will try the diagnostics the next time it comes up with the same error.